# Non-database field in Django model

Tags: django

Is it possible to have a field in a Django model which does not get stored in the database.
For example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    description models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    none_db_field = ????
```

I could then do

```
book = Book.objects.get(pk=1)
book.none_db_field = 'some text...'
print book.none_db_field
```

Thanks

Comment: The code in the second part of your example could be run without setting `none_db_field` in the class. What are you trying to accomplish by having a field not stored in the database?

Comment: If the three lines are all you want to do, you don't need anything additional in the class Book. You can add anything to the book object and it only persists in its scope.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As long as you do not want the property to persist, I don't see why you can't create a property like you described.  I actually do the same thing on certain models to determine which are editable.

```
class Email(EntryObj):
    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    editable = False
    ...


class Note(EntryObj):
    ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    editable = True
```

Comment: Now, when you call the `save()` method on an `Email` instance, it will also persist the `editable` field. How do I prevent it from persisting the `editable` field while persisting the rest?

Comment: Warning!! `editable` is a class variable if defined that way. You have to declare in `__init__` method as stated in python doc (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Answer (score 17):

[Creating a property](https://web.archive.org/web/20110126101237/http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/properties/) on the model will do this, but you won't be able to query on it.

Example:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def _get_full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def _set_full_name(self, combined_name):
        self.first_name, self.last_name = combined_name.split(' ', 1)

    full_name = property(_get_full_name)

    full_name_2 = property(_get_full_name, _set_full_name)
```

Usage:

```
from mysite.models import Person

a = Person(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
a.save()
a.full_name
'John Lennon'

# The "full_name" property hasn't provided a "set" method.
a.full_name = 'Paul McCartney'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
AttributeError: can't set attribute

# But "full_name_2" has, and it can be used to initialise the class.
a2 = Person(full_name_2 = 'Paul McCartney')
a2.save()
a2.first_name
'Paul'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've just tried this and it worked though.  I added none_db_field = None to my model. 

I then tried:
book.none_db_field = "testing" 
print book.none_db_field
and it worked.

Is this ok to do in Django?

Comment: Adding it to the model like that makes it a class attribute, which may or may not be what you want. Normally instance attributes are created in the `__init__()` method.

Answer (score 7):

To make it an instance variable (so each instance gets its own copy), you'll want to do this

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    #etc

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.editable = False
```

Each Book will now have an editable that wont be persisted to the database

Answer (score 1):

If you want **i18n** support:

```py
# Created by BaiJiFeiLong@gmail.com at 2022/5/2
from typing import Optional

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, verbose_name=_("Title"))
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Content"))
    _visitors: Optional[int] = None

    @property
    def visitors(self):
        return self._visitors

    @visitors.setter
    def visitors(self, value):
        self._visitors = value

    visitors.fget.short_description = _("Visitors")
```