# Factory boy in django for non-database fields

Tags: django, testing, factory-boy

I have a django model which, on save, triggers the creation of an account on an external service (not related to django in any way). For testing, though, I'd like to suppress this account creation. I can override the manager's save() method and pop the kwarg from there, or I could add a non-database-field property to the model as per [Non-database field in Django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250890/non-database-field-in-django-model) and check for that in my save method.

However, when I try to use factoryboy to create my objects, it seems to check for real fields in the model, which crashes due to the property not being a field.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    create_external_account = True
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if create_external_account:
            ...

class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
    name = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'name%d' % n)
    create_external_account = False
```

Any thoughts on how I can pass an extra parameter such as this through factoryboy?

Answer (score 3):

You can use exclude, which has been added in 2.4.0
See http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.FactoryOptions.exclude

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice this in the documentation, and it saved me a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

You can [customize](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Factory._create) the [_create](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy/blob/f81aba229a7492b11a331407f60fba1bd4d6522c/factory/base.py#L549) method.

You can also [disable signals](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html#disabling-signals) if the external account is created in a signal handler.

Comment: On the right track, but AFAICT this wouldn't let me set or unset the flag on a case-by-case basis; it would have to be set (or unset ) for the entire factory. In some tests I need to set this flag as I want to check the external accounts get created. I guess I could create two different factories, one which sets it, one which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

`factory_boy`'s `create()` calls your model's `MyModel.objects.create(**kwargs)` method.

When you write `MyModelFactory()`, this calls:

```py
obj = MyModel(name="name01", create_external_account=False)
obj.save()
return obj
```

Here, you should override your model's `__init__` method to handle your custom field:

```py
class MyModel(django.db.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.create_external_account = kwargs.pop('create_external_account', False)
        return super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```