# Django pass field from serializer to model.save() that is not present in the model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to pass fields that are present in serializer, but not present in model to model save method (I have complicated saving logic and I want to make some decisions in object creation based on these fields). How can I do that? I tried to add
`non_db_field = property` to model, but I still get error `MyModel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'negative_amount'`

Let's say my model is

```
class MyModel(AbstractModel):
    field1 = models.DateTimeField()
    field2 = models.BigIntegerField()
```

My serializer is

```
class MyModelSerializer(AbstractSerializer):
    field3 = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta(AbstractSerializer.Meta):
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my viewset is

```
class MyModelViewSet(AbstractViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
```

Comment: Can you share the model, serializer and viewset that you describe here?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this behavior in `serializer.save` method, for example, you can pop it from `validated_data` like that:

```
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        self.validated_data.pop("negative_amount")

        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fields=['field1', 'field2', 'field3']` in serializer instead of `fields='__all__'`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based partly on Sharpek's answer and partly based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54302000/9573694) answer:

In **serializer** I override **save** method:

```
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if 'field3' in self.validated_data:
            kwargs['field3'] = self.validated_data.pop('field3')
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

In **models** I override **init** method and define field:

```
    field3 = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'field3' in kwargs:
            self.field3 = kwargs.pop('field3')
        super(Reading, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```